# How can I take the information provided in a entrybox and put in in a string so I can store it in a textfile

Tags: python, text-files

So, I'm working on my own personal project at the minute.
I have a simple entry box in python that the user can enter anything into.
When the user selects the "submit" button at the bottom of the page it runs `User_Entry.delete(first=0, last=22)`
but I want it to store whatever the user has entered into the entry box as a string and then write it
to a text file.
How would I go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using tkinter? The code you provided isn't valid tkinter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using tkinter.
In that case, you can retrieve the contents of your entry box like this:

```
my_string = User_Entry.get()
```

Comment: thank you! this worked perfectly, now I can write the names stored in that string to a list and update that list to append to the text file! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `User_Entry.delete()` method after storing the value in a string. Save it in a text file as below -->

```
file1 = open("myfile.txt", "a")  # append mode 
file1.write(variable_where_input_is_stored) 
file1.close()
```

Then you can clear the `text_input`.